# LazyList OutOfMemoryError: memory Exhausted in android

Tags: android, lazy-loading

I have a problem that I am implementing LazyListAdapter for showing images in listview through caching and it is working well but in some cases it returns outofMemoryError: memory exhausted. I don't know why? Please suggest  any solution.

**Code:**

```
package com.TCC.android.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.TCC.android.R;
import com.TCC.android.collections.BrandListCollection;
import com.TCC.android.collections.CatedoryListCollection;
import com.TCC.android.collections.PriceListCollection;

public class PriceListLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
   // private   List<BaseInventoryItem> localItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public static Long id;
    public static int cat_id;
    public static String type;
    PriceListCollection priceList = PriceListCollection.getSingletonObject();

    // Pass in the list of items to adapt
    public PriceListLazyAdapter(Activity inputActivity) {
        activity = inputActivity;
       // localItems = inputItems;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return priceList.getDisplayNames().size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.price_item, null);
        }
        // Grab all of the layout elements in which we need ot insert content.
        TextView tvDisplayName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_PriceItem_Name);
        TextView tvRating1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_PriceItem_Rating1);

        TextView tvPrice1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_PriceItem_Price1);

        TextView tvMPG1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_PriceItem_MPG1);

        TextView tvYear1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_PriceItem_Year1);

        ImageView productImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.img_PriceItem);
       /* ArrayList<String> arr = catList.getMapRating().get("Toyota Paseo");
        System.out.println("The array================================>"+arr.get(0));
        System.out.println("The array================================2>"+arr.get(1));*/
            /*tvRating1.setText(catList.getMapRating().get(position).get(0));
            tvRating2.setText(catList.getMapRating().get(position).get(1));
            tvPrice1.setText(catList.getMapPrice().get(position).get(0));
            tvPrice2.setText(catList.getMapPrice().get(position).get(1));
            tvMPG1.setText(catList.getMapMpg().get(position).get(0));
            tvMPG2.setText(catList.getMapMpg().get(position).get(1));
            tvYear1.setText(catList.getMapYears().get(position).get(0));
            tvYear2.setText(catList.getMapYears().get(position).get(1));*/
        tvRating1.setText(priceList.getRating());

        tvPrice1.setText(priceList.getPrice());

        tvMPG1.setText(priceList.getMPG());

        tvYear1.setText(priceList.getYear());

       tvDisplayName.setText(priceList.getDisplayNames().get(position));
      // Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = catList.getMapMpg().keySet().iterator();
        /*while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            ArrayList<String> value=catList.getMapMpg().get(key);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Key: "+key+" Value: "+value.get(0)+" and "+value.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Key:"+key+" Value:"+value.get(0)+" and "+value.get(1));
        }*/
        //tvBrandName.setText(brandList.getDisplayNames().get(position));
        imageLoader.displayImage(priceList.getImages().get(position), activity, productImage);


        return vi;
    }

    // expose this method so that SearchResultActivity.onDestroy() can safely close the Thread.
    public void stopImageLoader() {
        if(imageLoader != null) {
            imageLoader.stopThread();
        }
    }
}
```

**ImageLoader.java:**

```
package com.TCC.android.adapters;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.TCC.android.R;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = new ConcurrentHashMap<ImageView, String>();

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {

            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }    
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        //start thread if it's not started yet
        if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
        InputStream is;
        //from SD cache
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {



            System.out.println("---------------------IMAGE URL: "+url);

            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("---------------------IMAGE URL: "+url);
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
        finally{
            bitmap = null;
            is=null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } 
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    //stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        //removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true)
                {
                    //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                            photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
                        if(tag!=null && tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if(Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //allow thread to exit
                System.out.println("This is the Exit Point............");
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(bitmap!=null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Comment: Bitmaps can take up significant amounts of memory. How big are the photos that you are loading? Can you scale them down to thumbnails prior to using them in the ListView?

Comment: Thanx for the comment Tony, but can u tell me how can I scale bitmap in thumbnails prior to using ListView?

Comment: Actually he has scaled the bitmap in ImageLoader class in decodeFile() method

Comment: @Andro Correct, but it may be more effective to download a pre-scaled lower-resolution image rather than performing load-time scaling.

Comment: How many items are typically displayed when the app runs out of memory?